# how to access modeladmin class instance from an inline class instance in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am collecting current instance of a modeladmin class from url in admin.py as shown below. But now if I try to create a new form, it throws error because the url does not contain any id. How do I work around it in a django way? How do I get current instance of a modeladmin class in an inline class instance?

Below is my code in the inline class that throws error.

```
def get_object(self, request, model):
    object_id = resolve(request.path).args[0]   #throws index error when 'add new form is clicked'
    try:
        object_id = int(object_id)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    return model.objects.get(pk=object_id)
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding a try and except block for IndexError. I still do not know how to access modeladmin instance from inline class instance.

Answer (score 3):

When you register the AdminClass in the admin_site, Django instantiate the admin class to save in the registry ( a dict), where the key is the ModelClass, and the value is the ModelAdminClass instance,

From Inline Instance you can access to the parent_model, and then search in the registy

```
def get_object(self, request, model):
    ...
    admin_site._registry[self.parent_model]
```

Comment: Excellent way, or `admin.site._registry`in my case!

Comment: How to access attribute of parent model from inline? I am trying to check values using clean from inline formset or inline form.